# Improve MySQLdb query

Tags: python

I have the following query in python-mysql:

```
self.cursor.execute('SELECT apple_id FROM main_catalog WHERE apple_id=%s', apple_id)
if not self.cursor.fetchone():
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO main_catalog 
                      (apple_id, provider_id, show_title, artwork_apple_url, title,
                       itunes_url, network_name, length, episode_production_number, synopsis)
                       VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''',
                       apple_id, provider_obj.pk, show_title, artwork_apple_url, episode_title, 
                       itunes_url, network_name, length, episode_production_number, synopsis)
```

This seems incredible verbose. Is there a way to write this more compactly and easier to read/understand?

Comment: if the column `apple_id` is unique, you can simply use `INSERT IGNORE` syntax.

Comment: Good idea. What about all the `%s`'s ? Is there a way to simplify that at all?

Comment: `', '.join( ['%s'] * 10 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use [pytho-sql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-sql/) or [sqlpuzzle](https://github.com/horejsek/python-sqlpuzzle) to be avoid of strings containing log SQL statements

```
catalog = Table('main_catalog')
catalog.insert(columns=[
    catalog.apple_id, user.provide_id],
    values=[['Foo', 'foo'], ['Bar', 'bar']])
)
```

Using this library you can build the query from a `dict`:

```
columns = [Column(catalog, col) for col in data.keys()]

sql = catalog.insert(
     columns=columns,
      values=[data.values()]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, so far there's no logical operations you can minimize into this peace of code. It's basically a query which inserts values into a table which has many fields. I doubt there's something you can do about it.

Comment: "peace of code" - best typo ever. I love it :) But unfortunately, this doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: @itsjeyd Of course it does. **No** or **Can't be done** can be valid answers, although a little short. This one even has reason why it's *no*.